# Using homebrew to install pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, pyinstaller

I am using python 2.7.0 and pygame 1.9.1, on OS X 10.10.5. The user guide for PyInstaller dictates that Mac users should use Homebrew, and I have it installed. I used it to install both Python and Pygame. But 'brew install PyInstaller' produces no formulae at all when typed into Terminal! So how can I use homebrew to install PyInstaller? This seems like it should be simple, and I'm sorry to bother you, but I have searched high and low with no result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pyinstaller docs are poorly worded and you may be misunderstanding their meaning.

> PyInstaller works with the default Python 2.7 provided with current
>   Mac OS X installations. However, if you plan to use a later version of
>   Python, or if you use any of the major packages such as PyQt, Numpy,
>   Matplotlib, Scipy, and the like, we strongly recommend that you
>   install **THESE** using either MacPorts or Homebrew.

It means to say "install later versions of Python as well as python packages with Homebrew", and not to say "install pyinstaller itself with homebrew". In that respect you are correct, there is no formula for pyinstaller on homebrew.

You can install pyinstaller with pip though: `pip install pyinstaller` or `pip3 install pyinstaller`. Then confirm the install with `pyinstaller --version`.